# Strange character set in Wordpress Visual Editor only

Tags: wordpress

Not sure exactly when this happened, but I do remember that when I set it up, this wasn't happening. My visual editors all look like this now and I have no clue where to start to fix it. This was Wordpress installed via Digital Ocean marketplace droplet, I've never messed with the DB. I've got two different sites that aren't related that are having the same problem.

[image: Default block when creating a page]

[image: Writing in WSIWYG field]

Comment: Which WordPress version you had setup?

Comment: It's version 5.3.2

Comment: Try with removing the `classic editor` plugin and after reinstall it.

Comment: I didn't have that plugin installed originally, but I could try installing it.

Comment: I installed the Classic Editor plugin and it solved my problem by replacing the interface with the old one. Still not sure why the new visual editor font gets messed up tho.